# python export chart from an existing xlsx

Tags: python, excel, charts, export, win32com

I have an xlsx created by python lib xlsxwriter, and there is a chart in it. My question is how can I use python code to export this chart and save as a jpg image?

My python code will run on CentOS, I found code below,but it seems only can run on windows:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
xlsApp = Dispatch("Excel.Application") 
xlsWB = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(r'/tmp/test/code.xlsx') 
xlsSheet = xlsWB.Sheets("sheet1") 
mychart = XlsSheet.Charts(1)  #'1' is the index of the chart object in the wb
mychart.Export(Filename=r'/tmp/test/MyExportedChart.png')
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

The xlsx file contains data, Excel application is needed to render it. **Hence the only way you can export a chart defined inside an Excel workbook is to run Excel and capture the chart**. This can be done manually by starting the application and select/copy, or **programmatically via win32com**. But **win32com only works on Windows** because it uses Windows's COM technology. The only OS you can run the code posted is on Windows, and Excel will only run on Windows. You might be able to run Wine from CentOS: it provides the ability to "embed" Windows in Linux, similar to VMWare Player (but they have quite different pros and cons). Easiest is then to just run the script in Wine (or your VMWare VM guest) running in CentOS, but make it output to a folder on the CentOS filesystem.

So from the above you should conclude the answer to your question is "no you can't from Linux" but if you can use Wine or VMWare Player from Linux then there is a way.

Comment: now i have created an excel file with chart in it by python on linux , can i get that chart from the existing excel file?  i want to insert that chart in email body.